# for a given $\kappa$, find a model of DLO with a greater cardinality that has a dense subset of size $\kappa$

Tags: cardinals, model-theory

So given a cardinal $\kappa$, i am trying to find a dense linear order with no end points of cardinality greater then $\kappa$ which has a dense subset of size $\kappa$

I think I'm almost there

What i did is to take some $M\vDash DLO$ of size $\kappa$ and then define $N$ to be the collection of subsets $U$ of $M$ such that $U$ has no greatest element and is closed from below, i.e if $x\in U$ and $y<x$ then $y\in U$ and with inclusion we can see that $(N,\subseteq )\vDash DLO$ and the map $x\mapsto \{y\mid y<x\}$ embed $M$ as a dense subset of $N$. Now i believe that $N$ is of size greater then $\kappa$ (maybe $2^\kappa$?) but i am unable  to show it... help?

I want to show it so i can prove that $DLO$ is not $\kappa$-stable for all $\kappa$.

Comment: I know that in your previous question you said you didn't know about the order property. You really should look it up though. The question you are trying to answer then reduces to showing that the formula $x<y$ has the order property.

Answer (score 2):

This won’t work, unfortunately: it’s possible that $|N|=\kappa$. (Consider, for example, the case in which $M$ is $\Bbb R$ with the usual order.)

HINT: Let $\lambda$ be the smallest cardinal such that $2^\lambda>\kappa$, and take the lexicographic order on ${^\lambda\Bbb Q}$, the set of functions from $\lambda$ to $\Bbb Q$. For your dense set look at functions of bounded support, where

$$\operatorname{supp}(f)=\{\xi<\lambda:f(\xi)\ne 0\}\;.$$

Comment: Thank you i see, But why is the dense set that you offer is of size $\kappa$?

Comment: You need to prove two things (1) the set of functions of bounded support has cardinality $\aleph_0^{<\lambda} = \sup_{\alpha<\lambda} \aleph_0^{|\alpha|}$, and (2) $\aleph_0^{<\lambda} \leq \kappa$ (using the defining property of $\lambda$ - you'll also need to use the easy observation that $\lambda \leq \kappa$).

Comment: @sha: See **Alex Kruckman**’s comment just above mine. (Sorry not to have answered sooner, but I only just woke up.)